# Why does this Python Dict code work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
def isPerm(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    a = dict()
    for char in s1:
        a[char] = True
    for char2 in s2:
        if a.get(char2) == True:
            continue
        else: return False
    return True
```

This is a function I wrote to find whether two strings are permutations of each other or not.
But I'm not sure why this works (I've been getting correct outputs) when I reason through it. From my knowledge, a dict is like a hash table.

For example if I have s1 and s2 as "ab" and "aab", this should give me False, which this functions does. Now, in the first for loop when I go to each char in s1 I have a dict with "a" and "b" mapped to True.

When I go to the second for loop, I check the dict value for "a" and it is True, so I continue. In the second character, I again get an "a" which is true and in the third iteration, "b" also gives me true. So, the function should have given me True but it gives me False. I'm baffled as to why it's working!

Comment: Think about `if len(s1) != len(s2):`

Comment: I think this will fail with `isPerm('aab', 'abb')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program works because, it returns `False` because of the first condition checked in the function.

```
if len(s1) != len(s2):
    return False
```

Since `ab` and `aab` are of different sizes, it fails immediately.

But, as [inspectorG4dget points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134566/why-does-this-python-dict-code-work/26134608#comment40963441_26134566), your program will fail for the input `aab` and `abb`.

To actually find out if one string is a permutation of another, you should count the number of times each character occurs in both the strings and if all the counts are equal, then return `True`. This can be done in Python with the help of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), like this

```
from collections import Counter
def isPerm(s1, s2):
   return Counter(s1) == Counter(s2)
```

The `collections.Counter` gives you a dictionary of characters and their corresponding counts. For example,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("aab")
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
>>> Counter("abb")
Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1})
>>> Counter("aab") == Counter("abb")
False
>>> Counter("aab") == Counter("aba")
True
```

An alternate way with just normal dictionaries,

```
def counter(s):
    d = {}
    for char in s:
        d[char] = d.get(char, 0) + 1
    return d

def isPerm(s1, s2):
    return counter(s1) == counter(s2)

assert isPerm("aab", "aba") == True
assert isPerm("aab", "abb") == False
```

Comment: Oh that totally makes sense. Thanks! One quick question though - what's the run time of counter? If it's O(n) then this algorithm would be O(n^2). Wouldn't sorting the two lists be better since that would be O(nlogn) ?

Comment: @AdityaBist How is it O(N ^ 2)? You are doing an O(N) operation twice. So it would still be O(N) only :)

Comment: No, @AdityaBist, it's not O(n^2), it's just O(n), since the Counters are created independently of each other, and the comparison of the Counters is also O(n).

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't word it correctly. Let's say I don't want to use Counter and this is my new code -
  for char in s1:
    a[char] = s1.count(char)
Would this be n^2? What's the runtime of count?

Comment: @AdityaBist **Please** don't post extended chunks of code in comments, since the indentation gets lost. Add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: @AdityaBist Using `count` would make your program run in O(N ^ 2). Please check the alternate way, just using normal dictionaries I included in the answer now.

Comment: @thefourtheye okay, thanks! I was trying to avoid external libraries

Comment: @addybist You are welcome :-) Also, `collections` is not an external library. You could also accept this answer if it helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

The code solution to check permutation is MUCH more simple. It also is `O(nlogn)` complexity. Just sort strings and compare result.

```
def isPerm(s1, s2):
    return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)
```